# How to find unicode planes for emojis in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, unicode, emoji

I have pandas dataframe containing emojis and I want to categorize them according to their [Unicode Planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).

```
emoji | unicode
---------------
    |  1F602
    |  1F60A
```

Expected Output

```
emoji | unicode | Plane
-----------------------
    |  1F602  |   1    
    |  1F60A  |   1
 ⛹   |  26F9   |   0
```

Here Plane 0 refers to the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) and Plane 1 refers to the Supplementary Multilingual Plane (SMP).

[NB: please use Safari on Mac, Firefox on Linux, Chrome on Windows to see this question with proper emoji symbols]

Comment: Note: a emojii are created by one or more than one codepoint (like many grapheme/"letters"). Flags (and other emoji) need plane `0xE`. You may find more information in https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/tr51-18.html

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks. Yap but there is some emojis fall into Plane 0. So basically I wanted to find the distribution of emojis over all planes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both  and  belong to [**Plane 1**, the Supplementary Multilingual Plane (SMP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane).

The following code snippet can exemplify an algorithm for getting *Unicode plane #* (it's `ord(ch)>>16`, see [bitwise right shift](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/bitwise_right_shift.html)).

```
for ch in '✌⛹☹☺☻':
    print( ch, '\t{:04x}\t'.format(ord(ch)), ord(ch)>>16)
```

> ```
> ✌       270c     0
> ⛹       26f9     0
> ☹       2639     0
> ☺       263a     0
> ☻       263b     0
>       1f602    1
>       1f60a    1
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I corrected plane information in my question for the corresponding emojis.

Comment: seems like the same logic doesn't work for the Zero Width Joiner (ZWJ) emojis like ‍‍ . Any suggestions on how to handle them for the same situation?

Comment: @abu Code points are in planes.  Emojis can be made up of multiple code points.  Your example uses five code points in planes 1/0/1/0/1.  How do you want to handle it?

Comment: @MarkTolonen sorry for not making it clear. I would label it then 1,0,1,0,1 or multi-plane. Is there a list of emojis based on planes 0 and 1 to quickly lookup? Thank you.

Comment: [Emoji ZWJ Sequence](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-zwj-sequence/). There you can find e.g. [‍‍ Family: Man, Woman, Girl](https://emojipedia.org/family-man-woman-girl/)… See also https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-zwj-sequences.html

Comment: Thank you. I saw them before and it can serve my purpose for now.

Answer (score 1):

Please always give a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help others help you.

According to your link on [Unicode Planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)),

> There are 17 planes, identified by the numbers 0 to 16, which corresponds with the possible values 00–10 (in base 16) of the first two positions in six position hexadecimal format (`U+hhhhhh`).

Based on that explanation, let's write a function to get that information.

```
# in the comments, we can use char = ''
def unicode_to_plane(char: str) -> int:
    unicode_codepoint = ord(char)       # 128512
    hex_repr = hex(unicode_codepoint)   # '0x1f600'
    hex_digits = hex_repr[2:]           # '1f600'
    plane = 0                           # Assume plane is 0 until proven otherwise
    if len(hex_digits) > 4:             # The plane is 0 if hex representation is four hex digits or less
        hex_plane = hex_digits[:-4]     # '1' (take away the last four characters)
        plane = int(hex_plane, 16)      # 1 (convert hex characters to integer)
    return plane                        # 1
```

Please note that the according to the [wiki on Emoji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji),

> Most, but not all, emoji are included in the Supplementary Multilingual Plane (SMP) of Unicode.

and the SMP is Plane 1.